# 'Stack' and georeference multiple JPGs

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, georeferencing

I have 11 Satellite images in .jpg format showing the same area but in 11 different years. They align perfectly and have the exact same extent. They are not georeferenced and have 3 bands each.

Is there a way to georeference them all at the same time?
My idea was to 'stack' them first, georeference them and 'unstack' them again.

That is how I want to avoid georeferencing the images one by one.

I made a VRT with QGIS but I don't know how to undo that VRT later so that I have the single rasters again. With ArcGIS I tried to mosaic them but it seems that it is not the right way.

Any idea?

Comment: You could save the georeferencing points of the first image and load again for each other image, so referencing the other 10 will take about 5 clicks each.

Comment: Thats how I did it and it worked fine for my 11 images. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool called "Composite Bands" https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/composite-bands.htm  that will stack your single bands into a multiclass raster.  Run this tool.  Then georeference your image.  To unstack them just right-click on the individual band in the catalog window, click export, and then "Raster to Different Format".